# How do I have Ruby YAML dump a Hash subclass as a simple Hash?

Tags: ruby, hash, yaml

I have a class `Foo` that is a subclass of `Hash`.

```
class Foo < Hash
  # whatever Foo-specific methods/etc
end
```

When I dump it to a file with YAML, it is written with a tag indicating the class.

```
> f = Foo.new
> f[:bar] = "baz"
> puts YAML.dump(f)
--- !ruby/hash:Foo
:bar: baz
```

I would like it to just be written as a plain old hash (not `!ruby/hash:Foo`)

```
> puts YAML.dump({bar:"baz"})
---
:bar: baz
```

...so that consumers of my data don't need to know about `Foo`. Is there a magic method to add to my class to convert itself for serialization, or a magic option to pass to YAML.dump?

Of course it is easy to convert one `Foo` object to a hash, but they may show up nested at any level inside the actual hash I'd like to dump, and I'd rather not have to do a search and replace.

Comment: It'd help if you show example code, example YAML output that demonstrates the problem and example output that shows how you want it to look. See the "e" part of http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with the (poorly documented) `encode_with` and `represent_map` methods. To customise the YAML serialisation of an object you provide it with an `encode_with` method which accepts a [`coder`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych/Coder.html) object, one of the methods on which is [`represent_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych/Coder.html#method-i-represent_map).

```
class Foo < Hash

  # other methods ...

  def encode_with coder
    coder.represent_map nil, self
  end

end
```

Now `YAML.dump` will just output your object as a normal hash.

## *However*

There is a bit of a problem because there is a bug that will cause this to fail and is [only fixed in the latest Gem version of Psych](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/commit/40df3b13deef0f1add3576428d3a7ab22197282d). It is *not* fixed in the current latest Ruby version (ruby 2.0.0p247). It [is fixed in Ruby trunk](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/2a58706e2d31abd5f708942254d46cda35aa60dd) so later patch releases should be okay.

In order to use this you will have to make sure you are using the latest Psych Gem, rather than the version bundled with Ruby. This should be as easy as

```
gem 'psych', '2.0.0'
```

before you require Yaml, but it seems that in Ruby 2.0 this doesn’t work for some reason that I can’t figure out. Using Bundler to specify the Gem versions does work though, so you might need to create a `Gemfile` and specify Psych in there if you’re not already using it.

Comment: This is probably the right answer going ahead... for now, with my ruby 1.9.3 codebase, I'm guessing I need to implement the search-and-replace.

Answer (score 0):

Search and replace was actually not too bad:

```
# Convert Hash/Array subclasses into plain hashes/arrays for YAML dump.
# Assumptions:
#   Hash keys will be simple objects - don't need to clear them
#   No custom objects containing Hash/Array subclass instances
def deep_clear_subclasses(obj, dedup = {})
  case obj
  when Hash
    return dedup[obj] if dedup.has_key? obj
    dedup[obj] = copy = {}
    obj.each {|k,v| copy[k] = deep_clear_subclasses(v, dedup)}
    copy
  when Array
    return dedup[obj] if dedup.has_key? obj
    obj.inject(dedup[obj] = []) {|a,v| a << deep_clear_subclasses(v,dedup)}
  else
    obj # not going to operate on other kinds of objects
  end
end
```